# Relative Binding in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have an ItemsControl in my application. The page associated with the ItemsControl is bound to a view-model. The view-model includes two properties: People and Options.  For each person, I want to display a list of options in a ComboBox. The options are defined in my view-model. My code looks like the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="Options" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

However, because each Item represents a Person, the ComboBox is looking at the Person object for a property called "Options".  How do I reference the view model for the from the ComboBox instead of the Person?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following technique

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.Options}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" />
```

Assuming that your LayoutRoot's DataContext is the View Model. If not you can give your ItemsControl a name and use that for the ElementName.